# Moderation request: Flags unhandled for months, please approve

Tags: support, status-completed, flags, moderation-request

Note that [*Stack Apps* is its own meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/60099/148310).

Sorry for nagging the mods, but I have flags that have sat in the "active" state since June 29th, and these flags apparently don't expire.

Can a moderator <strike>blanket approve my flags</strike> work to clear the flag queue, please? :)

If there are a lot in the queue, then maybe 15 minutes a week, until it's cleared?

Or, if the flags will eventually expire, and [I could find nothing to suggest they would](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflags%5D%20expire), then that would be a satisfactory answer too, AFAIWC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag I think you're referring to was a recommend closure flag, which results in the post [going to the Close Votes queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/191992/why-arent-some-helpfully-flagged-questions-closed/191994#191994) – not the actual flag queue, which currently has no backlog.

Our flag response time is pretty good at the moment, sitting at a little under two and a half hours. It had recently been even better than that recently, but I've admittedly been a bit distracted this week with the birth of my son (excuses!).

So...the real question is whether or not more attention be paid to the review queues, on account of the fact that there aren't many members here who can deal with such things. The answer to that is of course yes, given that for my part I had mostly just overlooked them here up until this point.

I'll make a point to try and pay more attention to them from here on out, and I'll be sure to take a look at the items in the close queue later today.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that "close" flags were moved from one queue to another.  Might be something for the help pages to note (if they don't already; I'll make a low-priority note to look into that). PS: Congrats on the baby!

Comment: Yeah, that is a bit confusing looking at it from the flag history page. It also doesn't help that there's no notification icon about the review queues like there is for flags, so I have to remember to check to see if there are new items (whereas the flag indicator in the top bar is quite apparent). And thank you!

Comment: Might be worth testing.  If these flags are in the close queue, maybe they'll expire when the question gets 100 views + 4 days (like close votes).